# What the differents variables will be destructured when I use rememberSaveable?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The Code A is from offical sample code [here](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/interests/InterestsRoute.kt).

The code `val (currentSection, updateSection) = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(tabContent.first().section) }` will create two variables, one is `currentSection`, another is `updateSection`.

According to the Hint of Android Studio, I find the following definition

```
val currentSection: Sections

val updateSection: (Sections) → Unit
```

I read the source code of both `tabContent` and `rememberSaveable`, but I can't understand why the `rememberSaveable` can destructure it to two different variables (`Sections` And `(Sections) → Unit)`. Why can't the `rememberSaveable` destructure it to three different variables with other types?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun InterestsRoute(
    interestsViewModel: InterestsViewModel,
    isExpandedScreen: Boolean,
    openDrawer: () -> Unit,
    scaffoldState: ScaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
) {
    val tabContent = rememberTabContent(interestsViewModel)
    val (currentSection, updateSection) = rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(tabContent.first().section)
    }

    InterestsScreen(
        tabContent = tabContent,
        currentSection = currentSection,
        isExpandedScreen = isExpandedScreen,
        onTabChange = updateSection,
        openDrawer = openDrawer,
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState
    )
}

@Composable
fun rememberTabContent(interestsViewModel: InterestsViewModel): List<TabContent> {
   ...
   return listOf(topicsSection, peopleSection, publicationSection)
}


class TabContent(val section: Sections, val content: @Composable () -> Unit)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The destructing that you are referring to has actually nothing to do with `rememberSaveable`.
The `rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(...) }` function returns a `MutableState` and this is what can be destructured.

```kotlin
interface MutableState<T> : State<T> {
    override var value: T
    operator fun component1(): T
    operator fun component2(): (T) -> Unit
}
```

Here you can see the two components that you are referring to ( `T` and `(T) -> Unit`)

Comment: Thanks! but I find three components  in the source code, why isn't  `operator fun component1(): T`   destructured?

Comment: I guess you are referring to nested destructuring where you can split one destructured component into its subcomponents. Unfortunately Kotlin doesn't support that. You can go through the discussion [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/should-kotlin-support-nested-deconstruction/4312)

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that only both `component1()` and `component2()`  in  `interface MutableState<T>` are destructured? why isn't  `override var value: T`  in  `interface MutableState<T>`  destructured?

Comment: Destructing fields are denoted by componentX named functions marked with `operator` keyword. You can refer to the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html)